# How to make a function determining the winner of Tic-Tac-Toe more concise

Tags: python, numpy

I'm writing a Python script which is supposed to allow human and computer players to play Tic Tac Toe. To represent the board, I'm using a 3x3 Numpy array with `1` and `0` for the marks of the players (instead of "X" and "O"). I've written the following function to determine the winner:

```
import numpy as np

class Board():
    def __init__(self, grid = np.ones((3,3))*np.nan):
        self.grid = grid

    def winner(self):
        rows = [self.grid[i,:] for i in range(3)]
        cols = [self.grid[:,j] for j in range(3)]
        diag = [np.array([self.grid[i,i] for i in range(3)])]
        cross_diag = [np.array([self.grid[2-i,i] for i in range(3)])]

        lanes = np.concatenate((rows, cols, diag, cross_diag))

        if any([np.array_equal(lane, np.ones(3)) for lane in lanes]):
            return 1
        elif any([np.array_equal(lane, np.zeros(3)) for lane in lanes]):
            return 0
```

So for example, if I execute

```
board = Board()
board.grid = np.diag(np.ones(3))
print board.winner()
```

I get the result `1`. What bothers me slightly is the repetition of the `any` statements. I would think there would be a more concise, DRY way of coding this. (I was thinking of a switch/case as in MATLAB but this doesn't exist in Python). Any suggestions?

Comment: It's _much_ more efficient to feed `any` a generator expression than a list comprehension. `any` short-circuits, i.e., it stops evaluating further elements as soon as it gets a True element. But if you pass it a list comp the whole list has to be built before `any` can start work on it. Whereas if you pass it a gen exp like `any(np.array_equal(lane, np.ones(3)) for lane in lanes)` the gen exp doesn't even generate the later elements. Similar remarks apply to `all`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to check the sum of `lanes`.

```
    s = np.sum(lanes, axis=1)
    if 3 in s:
        return 1
    elif 0 in s:
        return 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made a loop instead, and return only once, to conform with PEP8 and to be honest to my personal coding standards :)

`enumerate` in the correct order will yield `0,zeromatrix` then `1,onematrix`

```
rval = None
for i,m in enumerate([np.zeros(3),np.ones(3)]):
   if any([np.array_equal(lane, m) for lane in lanes]):
      rval = i; break
return rval
```

Comment: You don't need the `return None`, Python always returns `None` if `return` is not called

Comment: I know, but I thought it was a bad practice. Ok, then it's even shorter, thanks.

Comment: "Be consistent in return statements. Either all return statements in a function should return an expression, or none of them should. If any return statement returns an expression, any return statements where no value is returned should explicitly state this as return None , and an explicit return statement should be present at the end of the function (if reachable)." -PEP8

Comment: Ok, it WAS a bad practice after all :)

Answer (score 0):

I found out one way, by using a Lambda function:

```
any_lane = lambda x: any([np.array_equal(lane, x) for lane in lanes])

if any_lane(np.ones(3)):
    return 1
elif any_lane(np.zeros(3)):
    return 0
```

This adds an extra line to the code but makes it more legible overall, I reckon.

Comment: You could use `functools.partial` instead. Also the `[` and `]` are not only superfluous, they actually create a new list, first.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in two lines, starting from the board (`grid`): simple sums along columns, rows and the two main diagonals gives you a value of 0 or 3 depending on who is winning (or some intermediate values only if nobody is winning). You can thus calculate something like:

```
# Score along each column, row and both main diagonals:
scores = (grid.sum(axis=0).tolist() + grid.sum(axis=1).tolist()
          +[grid.trace(), np.flipud(grid).trace()])

# If there is no winner, None is declared the winner:
print "Winner:", 1 if 3 in scores else 0 if 0 in scores else None
```

where `flipud()` transforms the diagonal into the anti-diagonal (the diagonal at 90° from the main diagonal) by flipping the array horizontally, so that a simple `trace()` gives the total value along the anti-diagonal.